# Change Include Path of Interface library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have just created an interface library called "foo". Now I would like to include each of the modules of foo like this:

```
#include "foo/module.h"
```

Right now, I always have to write the include path as following

```
#include "foo/include/module.h"
```

Is it somehow possible to tell Cmake to ignore the "include" within the path? My CMakelists.txt of the Interface lib foo looks like this:

```
add_library(foo INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE 
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}> 
)
```

An the main CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1)

project(project)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(foo)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} foo)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it somehow possible to tell Cmake to ignore the "include" within the path?

That's not CMake's job. CMake is a build system that hands off the work of actually compiling the C++ text to the compiler and linker. CMake provides command line parameters and tracks which files need to be compiled, but it doesn't deal in how exactly the compiler parses a `#include` directive. It can affect that through command-line switches, but only to the extent that compilers permit it.

While every compiler allows users to define a set of directories to look in when processing include directives, to my knowledge, none of them will insert said directory text into the *middle* of the include string.

Most libraries that deliver headers will have them in an `include` or `inc` directory. When building code that links to this library, the path to that directory will be given as one of the include paths. Within that directory, they will usually have a `library_name` directory, and it is within that directory where the actual headers are.

That is, it's supposed to be "include/foo/module.h", which you would include with `#include "foo/module.h"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it totally makes sense.. :-D